# Iframe in Jupyter Notebook Pandas output

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I just started using Jupyter Notebook and Pandas. Now I want to show many rows (more then the default of 60). Anyhow, when increasing display.max_rows the results are displayed in an iframe (see attached image). How can I get rid of that frame, and see all results without frame.

Screenshot:

[image]

TS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jupyterthemes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) to customize the display font, width, color, etc. of your cells. In particular, I like those settings:

`jt -t onedork -fs 95 -tfs 11 -nfs 115 -cellw 88% -T`